# Uniswap 'PairCreated' Event Listener Temperamental

Tags: javascript, uniswap, ethers.js

Can anyone deduce why this doesn't show me all the PairCreated on Uniswap? It seems odd as I have seen it work once or twice during the day and ouput a log for a 'PairCreated', but I know there are many more that get added! Normally every 15mins or so.

Here is the beginning of the script...

```
const ethers = require('ethers');
const isTesting = false; // Kovan for testnet

const infuraWSS = isTesting ? 'wss://kovan.infura.io-------------' : 'wss://mainnet.infura.io----------------';

// SETUP
const addresses = {
  WETH: '0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2',
  factory: '0x5C69bEe701ef814a2B6a3EDD4B1652CB9cc5aA6f', //uniswap v2 factory
  router: '0x7a250d5630B4cF539739dF2C5dAcb4c659F2488D', //uniswap v2 router
  recipient: '-------------------' //this address receives the tokens (currently my main test account)
}

const mnemonic = '----------------------';

const provider = new ethers.providers.WebSocketProvider(infuraWSS);
const wallet = ethers.Wallet.fromMnemonic(mnemonic);
const account = wallet.connect(provider);

const factory = new ethers.Contract(
  addresses.factory,
  ['event PairCreated(address indexed token0, address indexed token1, address pair, uint)'],
  account
);
const router = new ethers.Contract(
  addresses.router,
  [
    'function getAmountsOut(uint amountIn, address[] memory path) public view returns (uint[] memory amounts)',
    'function swapExactTokensForTokens(uint amountIn, uint amountOutMin, address[] calldata path, address to, uint deadline) external returns (uint[] memory amounts)'
  ],
  account
);

factory.on('PairCreated', async (token0, token1, pairAddress) => {
  console.log(`** New Pair Detected **`);
    ...
```

Does anyone know why this might not be working? I took this from a repository, not all my code but I understand all of it - or at least think I do.

Comment: Is that issue resolved ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue seems to have been that the mnemonic did not match the 'recipient' wallet.